# How can I use CertificateException in TrustManager?

Tags: android-security, trustmanager

I uploaded my app to the play store and I received an email from Google developer that I have to modify my sentences in the https code. I am doing a data submission over https using the TrustManager function. I have a valid ssl certificate in my url and everything works perfectly. But I have a deadline to modify and add a CertificateException to the code.

Google send me:

**TrustManager**

You can find more information about TrustManager [in this Google Help Center article.](https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p/AD-FnEywowsfdWtw5BBOykfMB6rOzjhdOkxpoX43-4IrzA6ut0Fbe0_vIHOqSvmMwvIW8P3GhsDcJbW_BumxWu_Sk4OkxKUz1XH3mhIWA_2yiAY)

**HostnameVerifier**

Your app(s) are using an unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier interface. You can find more information about how resolve the issue [in this Google Help Center article.](https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p/AD-FnEyQNcReka5notZfad_dycqh9hFaLNCJxKn9PL1-KRHEPC8pKSdESkbcNToasOCYEhSCt6fhIkZv6vGPTTK4beiqwSECCweMLCazOg57oJQ)

**And this is my code:**

```
public class HttpsTrustManager implements X509TrustManager{

    private static TrustManager[] trustManagers;
    private static final X509Certificate[] _AcceptedIssuers = new X509Certificate[]{};
    private X509Certificate[] x509Certificates;

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(

            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s)
            throws CertificateException {

    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s)
            throws CertificateException {

    }

    public boolean isClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return _AcceptedIssuers;
    }

    public static void allowAllSSL() {
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                return true;
            }

        });

        SSLContext context = null;
        if (trustManagers == null) {
            trustManagers = new TrustManager[]{new HttpsTrustManager()};
        }

        try {
            context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context
                .getSocketFactory());
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

well in your code, you just trust everything.which is not safe.
as google said, you should judge the certificate and raise an Exception.
like this,

@Override
public void checkServerTrusted(
java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s)
throws CertificateException {

```
        // do some check here if the x509Certificates not valid just raise an CertificateException exception.

        // this will check the certificate          
        if(!checkTheHostName(x509Certificates[0]){
            throw new CertificateException("the certificate is invalid ...");
        }
}


private boolean checkTheHostName(Certificate certificate,String hostName){
    return OkHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE.verify("www.yourhostname.com",certificate)
}

the OkHostnameVerifier's code, just in 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/okhttp/+/e82a796/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/tls/OkHostnameVerifier.java
```

and the code

```
 @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostName, SSLSession session) {
                // here you should check the hostName, through session
                // do not just return true here, cause it's not safe. like man-in-middle-attack
               Certificate[] certificates = session.getPeerCertificates();
               return verify(host, (X509Certificate) certificates[0]);
    
            }
```